# How do you access exposed variables and functions in a custom view class Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view, android-livedata

Ideally, the end result is a way to access a custom view's parameters and functions to manipulate whats being shown, the input validation status, etc. I suppose Im looking to access it similar to a standard class.

I have an app that implements a block of payment fields in multiple views throughout. Depending on a payment type dropdown it changes the block between a bank entry and a credit card entry input set. I want a single class to handle the input fields and validation otherwise there is a ton of duplicate code in these views.

I created a PaymentInputView class that extends ConstraintLayout and implemented all the text watchers, field validation method, live data variables and public functions. Seems silly at this point but how do I use it? I would expect that I should be able to access public variables and functions from within my fragment or activity that implemented the custom view but I am not finding that to be the case.

In the XML I added the custom view.

```
<com.example.customviews.PaymentInputView
    android:id="@+id/payment_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/border_padding"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/payment_nickname_layout"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

In the Fragment I attempted to use databinding to access the methods or functions of the class but that doesnt seem to work as expected.

```
binding.paymentView.showFields.value = SHOW_CREDIT_FIELDS
```

So maybe this is because im accessing it incorrectly? Try by using a class reference.

```
val payView: PaymentInputView = binding.paymentView
payView.showFields.value = SHOW_CREDIT_FIELDS
```

The PaymentInputView is a bit larger. Not much development or testing has been done here, I haven't been able to implement it. The gist is here
https://gist.github.com/baggednismo/fd47d4058fb79602d6328c91724911e0

Comment: 1. Use custom text watcher for validation; 2. Use view model for fragment communication;

Comment: I was doing everything right, the problem was that I added the exposed parameters to a companion object which caused the issue of them being unreachable.